# How can I pronounce "quarter"?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter

I watched many YouTube videos and they seem to pronounce the first part of "Quarter" exactly the same as "core". It seems that the A is silent reading. Am I correct? Are there any accents that pronounce it like "QuAr"?

Comment: Yes, quart-er can sound like core-ter but not by all speakers. Some pronounce it as "ku-orter". Sorry, no phonetics or phonemics.

Comment: "Quarter" should have two syllables, although some speaker may "swallow" the second syllable when speaking quickly.  The "a" sound is more like the "o" sound as in "go" or "home".  Only a few dialects pronounce it like the "a" in "water", and never like the "a" in "quake".

Comment: It would sure help if you linked to one or two of those YouTube videos you are alluding to. Otherwise, we have no idea about what you are really hearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A always sounds like an O. I never hear it pronounced like an A.

It's the U that you hear disappearing in regular everyday speech. Sometimes it's briefly pronounced, but often not at all. You can see this described in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qClHsqoMbh0?t=51). You might hear the U if someone specifically emphasizes that word in a sentence.

I'm a native English speaker from Canada. I can't always speak about British English, but [this seems to be true there too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3fElgk32Q8).

Comment: No, not true; quintet, quartet, etc. very clearly have a phoneme created by the qu together. quintet is not qintet.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explicitly say this, but my answer only applies to the word "quarter" as that was the only word asked about. I'm not claiming anything about any other "qu" words.

Comment: I simply disagree with you.

Comment: @Lambie What about? That hardly anyone pronounces the U in quarter?

Comment: Lambie and Gabriel Luci, before you continue arguing this point, you might want to get some consensus on what sound the "q" makes without the "u". Since in normal English the 2 letters are never separated, it's not obvious whether the "q" by itself says "kw" (like "kwak-kwak") or simple "k" (like "Iraq"). That would make a difference in whether the "u" is pronounced or not.

Comment: That's right, the q is always with a **u**.  quarter is phonemically: kwɔ:tə///The qu sound is kw. Some people pronounce quarter as: core-ter, the core part is: k ɔ: Thereby changing the phonemes.

Comment: @LorelC Maybe you have a point? But I would be very surprised if anyone believed that Q on its own sounds like "kw". Then what would "qu" sound like? "Kw-w"? And no one says "Iraqw".

Comment: @GabrielLuci The kw is phonemic. Not alphabetic.

Comment: @Lambie *"Some people pronounce quarter as: core-ter, the core part is: k ɔ"* - So what do you disagree with then? You just said exactly what my answer says.

Comment: I disagree with you saying "it is disappearing in everyday speech".

Comment: Maybe you have a different experience then. In my experience (in Southern Ontario, Canada), I never hear the U pronounced unless someone is emphasizing the word.

Comment: In that case "hardly anyone" is regional. In BrE it is usually **kworter**. I am surprised, since the diction of Canadians is generally precise, however S. Ontario gets other influence, such as **kwarda**.